# User database authentication in Django

Tags: python, django

I have created a basic CRUD web application with Django. Whenever an operation is performed on the database, it's the 'server'-user that's performing the operations, defined by settings.py file:

```
default': {
    'ENGINE': "sql_server.pyodbc",
    'HOST': "MY-SERVER\SQL1",
    'USER': "AppFrontEnd",
    'PASSWORD': "MyPassword123",
    'NAME': "TEST_DB_1"
   }
```

Since I keep audit tables, I'd like to track where the changes are coming from and who is making them. We have a couple desktop applications that do this (Access) by using Windows passthrough authentication - but in Django I have to provide each specific users database login information.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question but here is for future Googlers that may have the same issue.

I just had the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51408934/per-user-database-authentication-in-django/51445784#51445784). While I could not find a way to log everything site-wide, I was able to make it work with select queries.

I was able to accomplish this by giving the SQL user the IMPERSONATE permission and performing EXECUTE AS prior to the DB queries that I needed to have logged in models.py.

```
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute("EXECUTE AS " + get_current_user()
    except DatabaseError as e:
        cursor.close()
        raise e
```