# Per user database authentication in Django

Tags: sql-server, django, django-models

Good afternoon,
I am writing a front-end for a research database that holds sensitive health information. My institution has a policy that user actions be logged by the SQL server so that they can perform audits on the server log files in the event of a breach.

Because of this policy, I cannot connect Django to the db as a system user  (otherwise, all users of the front-end actions would be logged by the server as the Django system user instead as the actual user individually).

Is there a way to connect to the DB using per user credentials so that actions performed on the front end will be logged as that user on the db server?  I have been able to find a lot of information about using multiple databases, but nothing about per user authentication of those databases.

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by giving the SQL user the IMPERSONATE permission and performing EXECUTE AS prior to the DB queries that I needed to have logged in models.py.

```
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute("EXECUTE AS " + get_current_user()
    except DatabaseError as e:
        cursor.close()
        raise e
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that, the user that connect to the database need to have access to all the tables.

I had a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51158299/django-models-access-outside-django-without-access-to-the-settings-file) when I wanted to use Django models outside Django and restrict access to certain models for certain users.

I ended up using [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) and its [automap](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html) feature on the existing Django database. Then you can connect to the database using your SQL users.

However, if you don't mind all the users accessing all the tables and are only concerned about the logs, maybe you can use a different `settings.py` or at least a different `DATABASES` configuration for each user?

Comment: Thank-you, I was previously unaware of the automap feature of SQLAlchemy, while it doesn't help my current issue, I am curtainly adding this to my toolbox for later use! I'll upvote once I have reputation to do so.